# where we can configure smtp in tfs 2015 online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We need to configure SMTP server to get alert email notification in TFS 2015 online version.

Where can we find this setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to configure SMTP server for Visual Studio Team Service, the email notifications are sent from "**visualstudioonline@microsoft.com**".

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to Visual Studio Team Services (visualstudio.com), then you don't need to configure anything.  Email notifications should just work.